# VBA VLookup is giving incorrect hyperlink folder location for SharePoint files

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

So I have an excel document which has 2 sheets, one for the search I've created and one sheet with data extracted from a Sharepoint

My data from the sharepoint comes with hyperlinks for the folder location and the data extracted now looks like this [image].

As you can see on column A I had the file with the hyperlink and in column B I only added the URL then in Column C i redid the Hyperlink ( *this was done to check if there was something wrong with VLookUP since when I'm using the Vlookup in the VBA code the hyperlinks dont send the user to the correct location, instead it sends them randomly ?* )

This is my current output of the VBA code below
[image]
The issue as mentioned earlier, user gets send to a different file location within the share point when using the code below.

The issue is that I'm unsure on what should I do to ensure the Hyperlink sends the user to the correct SharePoint location. *(Not sure if this affects the code but the sharepoint url are really long)*

```vb
Sub Hyperlink()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim spDataShheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, cellValue As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    Set spDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SharePointData")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 6 To lastRow
        cellValue = spDataSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
        If cellValue <> "" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = Application.VLookup(cellValue, spDataSheet.Range("A2:B100"), 2, False)
            ws.Cells(i, 4).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i, 4), Address:=ws.Cells(i, 4).Value, TextToDisplay:=ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
        End If
   Next i
        
End Sub
```

Note.1: Also in case it matters I'm using this code to call it after the user did a search using a search form, not sure it would be helpful to add the complete code since this Hyperlink sub is called after the search was performed

Note.2: I've also tried to simply paste the Vlookup Formula in the cells and I'm still getting a similar result where the user gets send to random location of the sharepoint.